# Validating nested list of numbers/booleans with JSON schema

Tags: json, validation, nested, jsonschema

I'm not sure if this is possible with JSON schema, but I have data similar to this:

```
[1, 1, [0, 0, [true]], true]
```

How can I validate [0, 0, 1] so that at least one of the items is 1/true?

So far, I have managed to create schema to this point:

```js
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/_items"
  },
  "definitions": {
    "_items": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "enum": [
            0,
            1
          ],
          "type": "integer"
        },
        {
          "enum": [
            false,
            true
          ],
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/_items"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Apparently it does validate all accepted values, but it doesn't take on account, if there are all, some, one, or none of the values 1 / true. I misunderstood, that anyOf, allOf and oneOf are reserved for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `contains` keyword.  This is planned to be added in the next version of the JSON Schema specification.  Until that is implemented, you can do it without `contains`, but the logic is a bit complicated.  I've also cleaned up some of the unnecessary bits from what you have so far.

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/_items" },
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/contains-1-or-true" }],
  "definitions": {
    "_items": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "enum": [0, 1] },
        { "type": "boolean" },
        { "$ref": "#" }
      ]
    },
    "contains-1-or-true": {
      "not": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "not": { "enum": [1, true] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up to very similar solution using not not notation. Can you please explain why anyOf ref # is needed here? Does this really work  recursively for deeply nested structure?

Comment: Yes, this will work with any level of nesting.  The `{ "$ref": "#" }` refers to whole schema.  It's a recursive reference.  Alternatively, you could do it by duplicating the first three lines (similar to what you had).  But, the recursive reference is a cleaner solution because it eliminates the duplication.

Comment: I opened other question very much related to this, you @Jason might be anble to give an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026162/xor-logic-in-json-schema-for-list-of-boolean-items